# Parsing a Java List<List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>> using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, jsonpath

I have parsed the following JSON String using JSON Path:

```json
{
    [
         [
            {
                "ID": "ExternalKey",
                "Name": "ExternalKey",
                "Label": "ExternalKey",
                "ExternalKey": "",
            "TranslatedName": "ExternalKey",
            "Type": "caption",
            "Self": "https://aqb629.saas.contentserv.com/admin/rest/product/Attribute/ExternalKey",
            "Value": "VSCHL01",
            "FormattedValue": "VSCHL01"
            },
            {
            "ID": "PdmarticleID",
            "Name": "PdmarticleID",
            "Label": "PdmarticleID",
            "ExternalKey": "",
            "TranslatedName": "PdmarticleID",
            "Type": "_id",
            "Self": "",
            "Value": 99942,
            "FormattedValue": 99942
            }
        ],
        [
            {
                "ID": "ExternalKey",
                "Name": "ExternalKey",
                "Label": "ExternalKey",
                "ExternalKey": "",
                "TranslatedName": "ExternalKey",
                "Type": "caption",
                "Self": "",
                "Value": "VSCHL02",
                "FormattedValue": "VSCHL02"
            },
            {
                "ID": "PdmarticleID",
                "Name": "PdmarticleID",
                "Label": "PdmarticleID",
                "ExternalKey": "",
                "TranslatedName": "PdmarticleID",
                "Type": "_id",
                "Self": "",
                "Value": 99944,
                "FormattedValue": 99944
            }
        ]
    ] 
}
```

I get the following `List` of `List`s in Java:

```java
List<List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>> productsMasterMap = jsonContext.read(jsonPath);
```

I would like to do a search via streams where for ID = PdmArticleID and Value=99924 I would get the following structure:

```json
[
    {
        "ID": "ExternalKey",
        "Name": "ExternalKey",
        "Label": "ExternalKey",
        "ExternalKey": "",
        "TranslatedName": "ExternalKey",
        "Type": "caption",
        "Self": "https://aqb629.saas.contentserv.com/admin/rest/product/Attribute/ExternalKey",
        "Value": "VSCHL01",
        "FormattedValue": "VSCHL01"
    },
    {
        "ID": "PdmarticleID",
        "Name": "PdmarticleID",
        "Label": "PdmarticleID",
        "ExternalKey": "",
        "TranslatedName": "PdmarticleID",
        "Type": "_id",
        "Self": "",
        "Value": 99942,
        "FormattedValue": 99942
    }
]
```

Which is a `List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>` object. How can I achieve that? I have tried the following:

```java
List<LinkedHashMap> listOfMaps =    

productsMasterMap.stream().filter(listOfHashMaps->
                
listOfHashMaps.stream().filter(m->m.get("ID").equals("PdmarticleID") &&   

m.get("Value").equals("99945"))
                     
map(m->m).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I would like to get the inner list element where the condition is true.

Comment: Please, you don't have to do this. Use real POJOs and a real JSON parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Stream.anyMatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) on the inner stream to find if any of the maps matches your condition:

> Returns whether any elements of this stream match the provided predicate. May not evaluate the predicate on all elements if not necessary for determining the result.

Then you can use [Stream.findFist()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) to get the first match:

> Returns an Optional describing the first element of this stream, or an empty Optional if the stream is empty.

```
List<List<LinkedHashMap<String,String>>> productsMasterMap = ...;

Optional<List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>> listOfMaps = productsMasterMap.stream()
            .filter(listOfHashMaps -> listOfHashMaps.stream()
                    .anyMatch(map -> map.get("ID").equals("PdmarticleID") && map.get("Value").equals(99944)))
            .findFirst();
//handle the Optional
```

If there can be more than 1 match and you care about those matches, instead of `findFirst` collect to a list.

As a side note, i would use a custom class, instead of `Map`, the elements have the same properties. It will make the code much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

As @Chaosfire mentioned you need the flatmap.
For your case it would be like this if you need the inner list element as the filter result:

```
    String searchId = "PdmarticleID";
    String searchValue = "99924";
    Optional<Map<String, Object>> result = productsMasterMap.stream()
            .flatMap(List::stream) // Flatten the nested lists
            .filter(map -> searchId.equals(map.get("ID")) && searchValue.equals(map.get("Value")))
            .findFirst();
```